# In Python, how do you "install the repository version?"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying out the examples from the [IMDBPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/index.html) website. They don't work. As a fix someone said "you have to install the repository version, without using easy_install or pip, until we've packaged a newer version."

I'm very new to Python. I'm not even sure what the repository version is, let alone how to install it. Could someone please explain? If it matters, I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Someone" may have misled you slightly by saying:

> ... without using easy_install or pip

You may still use pip when installing the repository version.  They probably meant to say that you can not install the current version from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/) yet.

In your shell:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy.git
```

Then cd into the `imdbpy` directory (the directory where you have the `setup.py` file contained).  Optionally create/activate a virtual environment, and then:

```
$ pip install .
```

Answer (score 0):

Repository version means you will need to checkout their repository on Github or other Subversion system  they are hosting the code on. For `git`, that means cloning the repository to your local machine.
Like so: `git clone https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy`